When you load test the logic using jedis, the lendis connection is disconnected
I'm developing a like function using Redis. First of all, I'm trying to implement a logic that saves Redis the number of likes and who requested it and then synchronizes it to DB every certain time.
However, there was an exception when I asked for a request of 1000 at the same time using jmeter.
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException
@Configuration

public class ProductRedisConfig {

    private final String redisHost = "localhost";
    private final int redisPort = 6379;
    private final String redisPassword = "systempass";
    

    @Bean
    public Jedis jedis() {

        Jedis jedis = new Jedis(redisHost, redisPort, 5000);
        jedis.auth(redisPassword); 
        jedis.getClient().setSoTimeout(5000); 

        return jedis;
    }
}

public void addLike(UUID userId, UUID productId) {
    String likeCountKey = productId.toString() + ":likeCount";
    String userListKey = productId.toString() + ":userList";
    String lockKey = "post:like:" + productId;


    String likeCount = jedis.get(likeCountKey);

    if (likeCount == null) {

        Product product = productRepository.findByIdAndIsDeleteFalse(productId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("not found."));
        likeCount = product.getProductLike().getLikeCount().toString();


        jedis.set(likeCountKey, likeCount);
    }


    jedis.incr(likeCountKey);

    jedis.sadd(userListKey, userId.toString());
}

Here's the code.
